# How to handle multiple error using view model in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to jetpack compose and I was wondering how I can cleanly handle multiple server errors. I remember doing something similar before using fragments.

in my viewModel I have

```
private val _errorBase = MutableLiveData<ErrorHelper>(
val errorBase: LiveData<ErrorHelper> = _errorBase
```

And calling this on my login Function like this

```
fun login(a, b){
  
    when(r){

    is Result.Error -> 
   _errorBase.postValue(r.error as ErrorHelper)
}


}
```

my error helper function

```
 private fun onError(errorHelper: ErrorHelper) = when (errorHelper.errorStatus) {
        ERROR_STATUS.ERR -> message
        ERROR_STATUS.NETWORK -> message
        ERROR_STATUS.INVALIDCRED -> message
        else -> message
    }
```

ErrorHelper is a throwable class with an enum

My question now is on my compose I have this `if(state is Fail)` show the `onError` function with error thrown. I am however now sure how to call this, before I would do something like this  `lViewModel.errorBase.observeWith(this, this::onError)` but now not sure where to add handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the a new dependency to build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta01'
```

And then:

```
val errors = viewModel.errorBase.observeAsState()
```

This will work for you but generally, is better to use `StateFlow`